# Does AssemblyLoadContext isolate static variables?

Tags: c#, static, .net-assembly, .net-core-3.0, assembly-loading

[Announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-0/) tells us:

> Assembly unloadability is a new capability of AssemblyLoadContext. This new feature is largely transparent from an API perspective, exposed with just a few new APIs. It enables a loader context to be unloaded, releasing all memory for instantiated types, **static fields** and for the assembly itself. An application should be able to load and unload assemblies via this mechanism forever without experiencing a memory leak.

Also, this [design notes](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/v2.1.0/Documentation/design-docs/assemblyloadcontext.md) has mentioning of "statics".

I have tried this straightforward test:

```
static void Main()
{
    Proxy.X = 15;
    var alc = new AssemblyLoadContext("MyTest", true);
    var asm = alc.LoadFromAssemblyName(typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName());
    var proxy = (Proxy)asm.CreateInstance(typeof(Proxy).FullName);
    Console.WriteLine(proxy.Increment());
}

class Proxy
{
    public static int X;
    public int Increment() => ++X;
}
```

It outputs "16", which means that isolation doesn't work.

My goal is to unit-test class static members which can throw exceptions. Usual tests can affect each other's behavior by triggering type initializers, so I need to isolate them in the cheapest possible way. Test should run on .NET Core 3.0.

Is it right way to do it, and can `AssemblyLoadContext` help with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does isolate static variables.

If we look at the [newest design notes](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/design-docs/assemblyloadcontext.md), we see this addition:

> **LoadFromAssemblyName**
>
> This method can be used to load an assembly into
>   a load context different from the load context of the currently
>   executing assembly. The assembly will be loaded into the load context
>   on which the method is called. If the context can't resolve the
>   assembly in its **Load** method the assembly loading will defer to the
>   **Default** load context. In such case it's possible the loaded assembly
>   is from the **Default** context even though the method was called on a
>   non-default context.
>
> Calling this method directly on the **AssemblyLoadContext.Default** will
>   only load the assembly from the **Default** context. Depending on the
>   caller the **Default** may or may not be different from the load context
>   of the currently executing assembly.
>
> This method does not "forcefully" load the assembly into the specified
>   context. It basically initiates a bind to the specified assembly name
>   on the specified context. That bind operation will go through the full
>   binding resolution logic which is free to resolve the assembly from
>   any context (in reality the most likely outcome is either the
>   specified context or the default context). This process is described
>   above.
>
> To make sure a specified assembly is loaded into the specified load
>   context call **AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath** and specify the
>   path to the assembly file.

It's little bit frustrating, because now I need to determine the exact location of the assembly to load (there's no easy way to "clone" already loaded assemblies).

This code works (outputs "1"):

```
static void Main()
{
    Proxy.X = 15;
    var alc = new AssemblyLoadContext("MyTest", true);
    var asm = alc.LoadFromAssemblyPath(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location);
    var proxy = asm.CreateInstance(typeof(Proxy).FullName);
    Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetType().GetMethod("Increment").Invoke(null, null));
}

class Proxy
{
    public static int X;
    public static int Increment() => ++X;
}
```

*(Notice, now we can't cast to `Proxy` class, because it is different from the run-time class of `proxy` variable, even being the same class...)*